# When running docker image it shows error cannot find name for group ID 1000

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, yocto, bitbake

I am using Ubuntu in virtual machine. I have cloned my git repository in a directory in `/home/Yocto_Dev` using git clone command.

Below are the commands executed.

1. `git clone`
2. `docker build -t ubuntu-yocto-kirkstone`
3. `docker run -it --name my_container -v /home/chandra/.ssh/root/.ssh   -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)"ubuntu-yocto-kirkstone /bin/bash`

command throw below error

```
**groups: cannot find name for group ID 1000
I have no name!@72cd4f3f84bd:/$**
```

*Note: Ubuntu machine and Docker container user ids are not same.*

My goal is: To copy local SSH keys inside docker container and clone the repository inside docker container.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve]?  The "I have no name" message is harmless; you'll never see it when you're running your application normally, only if you're using a debugging shell in a container for some reason.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze: I edited question. I hope it is easy to understand now. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your user to the docker group

```
sudo usermod -aG docker yourusername
```

You can refresh the group by running the command or logoug and log back in again

```
sudo `newgrp docker`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: All of these are in the Host? In my case doing `cat /etc/groups` I can see that the user is in docker group `docker:x:998:myuser`